# Shadow darkness variations?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, light, shadows, scene

In my scene, I have one object that's casting a very pleasantly dark shadow (not too dark, not too bright), and on another object, the shadows seem to be much lighter... Is there anything I'm missing or am I just being dumb... (And the material is nearly the same shade) The picture below (CYCLES) depicts a dark shadow on the big object, and light shadow on the small object.
[image]

And in the image below here (Rendered in EEVEE) The shadow darkness seems to switch.

[image]

Why do I get this feeling that the shadows are not cooperating equally in comparison to size and object.

Comment: It's tough to say without seeing the blend file.  Are ships imported?  There are a lot of possibilities for inconsistencies in materials on imported files.  May try rendering in Cycles without the Star Destroyer, does the top of the X-Wing still look bright?  It may be getting reflected light from the Star Destroyer.

Comment: Yeah the ships are standard imported FBX. And I made these simple Principled BSDF materials. Nothing crazy. And I’ll give that a shot with the Xwings only. Maybe I can render each object with the lighting I want for each...

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I was just going through my old comments looking for something and came back across this.  I realized something we didn't address is that it might have been a normals issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is probably just because of the differences between Cycles and Eevee.  Eevee only "guestimates" the lighting, while Cycles calculates each beam of light and it's bounces. This is one of the reasons it is good to plan for which render engine you are planning on using before you start the lighting process.

BTW, I like your images. :)

Comment: Thank you! And Yeah but right now, there's just a simple sun lamp currently. No other lighting exists in the scene.

Comment: sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean "but right now, there's just a simple sun lamp currently. No other lighting exists in the scene". What part of my answer is that a reply to? :)

Comment: I was replying to your comment about fixing my lighting after I figure out my render engine. And I was basically saying that my lighting set up isn’t really complex and only contains a simple sun lamp.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. :)  Personally, I can't wait to see how good eevee will be when there's a 2.90 :)